# JSON-LD serialization string without indentation, spaces or line breaks in RDF4J / Sesame

Tags: java, rdf, jena, sesame, rdf4j

I am trying to serialize a Model as JSON-LD and store it in a string variable using RDF4J.

My code looks like this:

```
public void storeAsString(Model model) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    RDFWriter rdfWriter = Rio.createWriter(RDFFormat.JSONLD, stringWriter);

    rdfWriter.getWriterConfig().set(JSONLDSettings.JSONLD_MODE, JSONLDMode.COMPACT);
    rdfWriter.getWriterConfig().set(JSONLDSettings.OPTIMIZE, true);

    Rio.write(model, rdfWriter);
    String output = stringWriter.toString();
}
```

It gives me a JSON-LD string, but without any indentation, spaces or line breaks such that `System.out.println(output)` is not human-readable. It looks like this:

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org/","type":"Person","jobTitle":"Professor","name":"Jane Doe","telephone":"(425) 123-4567","url":"http://www.janedoe.com"}
```

In Apache Jena there is an `RDFFormat` called `JSONLD_PRETTY` which would give me the desired output format. It looks similar to this:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "id": "_:b0",
      "type": "Person",
      "jobTitle": "Professor",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "telephone": "(425) 123-4567",
      "url": "http://www.janedoe.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this also possible with Eclipse RDF4J?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**
When I am trying to store the JSON-LD string with MongoDB it throws this error: `Invalid BSON field name`. Is this an issue with the serialization or with my built model?

**Edit No. 2:**
The above code works flawlessy with the Turtle format, for example. I am having this problem just with JSON-LD **and** RDFJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, by setting the `BasicWriterSettings.PRETTY_PRINT` option to `true`:

```
rdfWriter.getWriterConfig().set(BasicWriterSettings.PRETTY_PRINT, true);
```

No idea about the MongoDB issue, sounds like it should be a separate question.

Comment: First of all, thank you! That is the setting I was looking for.

But there is a new problem: `JSONLDMode.FLATTEN` as well as `JSONLDMode.EXPAND` does not deliver well-formed JSON. The first character in the string is `[`and not `{`. That is maybe the reason why it is not storable in MongoDB. Furthermore, it does not use the namespaces I have declared, so there is no `@context` object. 

But if I use `JSONLDMode.COMPACT` everything works just fine. Do you know what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: It looks as if it turns it into an array with one element. This is in fact well-formed JSON, but admittedly it is a bit odd. I'm not immediately sure why this happens - I suggest you log a [support request](https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues) with the RDF4J project.